# Subscribe to single item with defined "retries" and "timeout"

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<Packet>` which is a hot observable, that allows different subscriptions to analyze incoming packets.

I want to write a method, that sends some data with and ID, and waits for response with the same ID. Pseudocode:

```
void SendData(byte[] data, int retries, int timeout, Action<Packet> success, Action fail) 
{
    var sequenceId = GetSequenceId();
    _port.SendData(data, sequenceId);
    _packetStream.Where(p => p.SequenceId == sequenceId)
                 .Take(1)
                 .WaitForTimeout(timeout)
                 .WaitForRetry(retries)
                 .Subscribe(success) //Need to unsubscribe after packet is received
    //If we didn't receive an answer packet, then call fail() action 
}
```

Don't really know, how this stuff is usually done with Reactive Extensions. Would be really glad to receive some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question looks close to right.  The two "wait for" methods exist in the Rx framework ([Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244283%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [Retry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229233%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)).  I would recommend you change your method to return an `IObservable` and drop the `success` and `fail` parameter.  Doing so "keeps you in the monad" and lets you chain further operators onto the observable if needed.  The success and fail parameters are instead used when you subscribe to the resulting observable (as OnNext and OnError respectively).

I assume the data should be resent on a timeout (otherwise you are not really retrying).  To do that, you can use `Observable.Create` to send the data upon subscription.

```
IObservable<Packet> SendData(byte[] data, int retries, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    //only get the sequence id once per call to SendData, regardless of retries
    var sequenceId = GetSequenceId();
    return Observable.Create(obs =>
        {   //this code runs every time you subscribe
            _port.SendData(data, sequenceId);
            return _packetStream.Where(p => p.SequenceId == sequenceId)
                                .Take(1)
                                .Timeout(timeout)
                                .Subscribe(obs)
        })
        .Retry(retries); 
}
```

Putting the `Retry` operator at the end causes, the Create observable to be retried if it times out.  As an aside, there are overloads of Timeout that allow you to pass in another observable sequence to use in the case of timeout.  You can use this overload along with `Observable.Throw` to provide your own exception in case of a timeout if desired, such as to provide an alternate error message.

Note that this code **does not** send data until you subscribe and **does not** block until the result is returned or the timeout is reached but does let you cancel further retries by Disposing the subscription.  This code also does not prevent you from sending multiple packets at the same time.  If you *must* block, you can do something like this:

```
var response = SendData(/* arguments */);
response.Do(success, fail).StartWith(null).ToTask().Wait();
```

If you are using C# 5 and calling this within an async method, you can await the observable.

Comment: This looks right, but I still don't understand where it will unsubscribe after operation is finished. I will have lots of calls to this method, so it can hurt, if there will be dangling subscriptions left. Also, why do I need StartWith(null)?

Comment: @ionoy StartWith(null) is needed because of how ToTask behaves if the observable completes without an item or an error.  ToTask and await will handle the unsubscription. If you subscribe manually, you are responsible for unsubscribing. As noted in another comment, operators in the framework all unsubscribe themselves on error or completion, so unsubscribing is only strictly needed for early termination.

Comment: I would like to point out here that the code above looks pretty much correct, except I dont think you want the SendData call made on each retry? If this is the case then it needs to be moved outside of the Create, or the Retry needs to be moved between the .Timeout(timeout) and .Subscribe(obs).

Comment: @LeeCampbell If you don't resend the data, you might as well just increase the timeout and forget the "retries" altogether.  It is common to resend packets in case they do not make it the first time, especially for things like serial ports that do not "guarantee" delivery.  A sequence id or similar mechanism can then be used to ensure the packet is not processed twice.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Gideon. It seems a reasonable reason to keep the send where it is.

Answer (score 0):

What I got so far is this:

```
private void WaitForAnswer(byte sequenceId, int timeout, Action<Packet> success, Action fail, int retriesLeft)
{
    _packetStream.Where(p => p.GetSequence() == sequenceId)
                 .Take(1)
                 .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
                 .Subscribe(success, 
                            _ => {
                                if (retriesLeft > 0) WaitForAnswer(sequenceId, timeout, success, fail, --retriesLeft);
                                else fail();
                            }, 
                            () => { });
}
```

I'm not quite sure though, if this solution correctly disposes of subscription.

Comment: Your code doesn't dispose of the subscription at all.  As an *implementation detail* however, the built-in operators you used here all have "auto-detach" behavior, meaning they dispose themselves when the observable terminates.  More importantly, this code does not wait for the answer before returning as the name implies it does.

Comment: I didn't specify that I don't really need to actually block while waiting. I can use Wait method, as you already suggested in your answer to do that. Usually though, I'll just supply something to react on success/fail. My final solution today was using separate Subject, returning Observable with it and using OnNext/OnComplete inside original Subscription. But code in your answer seems cleaner.

Comment: Also, my original Observable will not terminate until the very end, so that probably means I will have thousands of subscriptions after half an hour, which will definitely hurt performance.

Comment: Both the `Take(1)` and the `Timeout` will cause the subscribed to observable to terminate (on the first matching packet or after a timeout respectively) regardless of if _packetStream does.  Barring packets sent while another is in progress, you should only have a single subscription at a time.

Comment: But technically I would still be able to wait for multiple answers with similar code?

Comment: Yes. You will have one subscription per packet you are listening for.